Nuxt, не работает logout с привязанным доменом
Вкратце: У меня есть проект, запущенный в Docker, который состоит из нескольких API-контейнеров на PHP и фронтенда на Nuxt.js. Всё это работает через Nginx-прокси и доступно извне по доменному имени. Авторизация реализована через Cookies с помощью модуля @nuxtjs/auth.
Конфигурация Nuxt.js:
auth: {
    baseURL: apiURL,
    globalAppMiddleware: true,
    provider: {
        type: 'local',
        endpoints: {
            signIn: { path: 'auth/login', method: 'post' },
            signOut: { path: 'logout', method: 'post' },
            signUp: { path: 'auth/register', method: 'post' },
            getSession: { path: 'auth/profile', method: 'get' },
        },
        pages: {
            login: '/account/signin',
            callback: '/account/confirm',
        },
        auth: {
            token: {
                storage: 'cookie',
                cookie: {
                    name: 'auth_token',
                    options: {
                        path: '/',
                        domain: 'ОСНОВНОЙ ДОМЕН',
                        secure: true,
                        sameSite: 'none',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        sessionDataType: {
            user: 'user',
            profile: 'profile',
            exp: 'exp',
        },
    },
    globalMiddlewareOptions: {
        allow404WithoutAuth: true,
        addDefaultCallbackUrl: '/account/confirm',
    },
    session: {
        maxAge: 155 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60,
    },
},

Проблема:

При доступе к приложению по IP-адресу всё работает корректно.
При доступе через доменное имя, после авторизации и попытки выйти из аккаунта, сессия не удаляется.
При обновлении страницы пользователь остаётся авторизованным.

Выход из аккаунта реализован через стандартный метод:
<template>
<nuxt-link
  class="dropdown-item"
  @click="() => signOut({ callbackUrl: localePath('/logout') })"
>
  <i class="mdi mdi-logout text-muted fs-16 align-middle me-1"></i>
  <span class="align-middle" data-key="t-logout">Logout</span>
</nuxt-link>
<template>

<script>
const { signOut, status, data, token } = useAuth();
</script>


Почему при доступе через доменное имя сессия не удаляется при выходе из аккаунта, и как это можно исправить?
Я пробовал на стороне API выдавать сессию для определенных доменов, но это ничего не изменило.
